# How do I plot an address using UWP MapControl

Tags: win-universal-app

For the Universal Windows Platform (UWP) MapControl, I want to plot a street address. Unfortunately, as far as I know, the control only accepts Geopoint locations for Center.

Ex:

```
myMap.Center =
    new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()
    {
        //Geopoint for Seattle 
        Latitude = 47.604,
        Longitude = -122.329
    });
```

How do I convert a street address to a Geopoint location and back again? Is there another way to plot street addresses?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a street address to a Geopoint location and back again, you can use the [`MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn636926.aspx) and  [`MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAtAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.services.maps.maplocationfinder.findlocationsatasync.aspx) method.

> Convert addresses to geographic locations (geocoding) and convert geographic locations to addresses (reverse geocoding) by calling the methods of the MapLocationFinder class in the Windows.Services.Maps namespace.

For more info, see [Perform geocoding and reverse geocoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt219697.aspx).